# Identical Clusters after Text Clustering in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, tf-idf

I'm performing text clustering on a set of textdata in Python. Basically, I use tf idf score and then apply the result matrix into the kmeans algorithm just like that:

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=100,stop_words=sw) 

dtm = vect.fit_transform(df) 
l=vect.get_feature_names()

k = 15
model = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k)
model.fit(dtm)

order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
terms = vect.get_feature_names()
for i in range(k):
       print("Cluster %d:" % i, end='')
       for ind in order_centroids[i, :100]:
           print(' %s' % l[ind], end='')
       print()
```

Then after performing the following, I get 15 identical clusters (with almost fully identical word terms in it). I also tried the normalization using LSA method but it gives almost the same.

What am I doing wrong and how it can be fixed?

Comment: can you upload the data? also what version of sklearn do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your features are not standardized, meaning that some columns in `dtm` contain distributions centered around a higher mean than others. The sort you use to extract cluster-associated features will therefore wrongly favor these features.

A common practice to avoid such problems is to [standardize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Standardization) your features to `zero mean` and `unit variance` like this:

```
dtm_standardized = (dtm - dtm.mean(axis=0)) / dtm.std(axis=0)
```

or like this:

```
dtm_standardized = sklearn.preprocessing.scale(dtm)
```